# API data call Shopify

Tags: api

thank you for viewing my question.

Can anyone please help me with a data retrieval function on my Shopify site? I'm trying to call variables from an API that returns the following data when I access the URL (I've replaced certain parts of the URL with "XXX" for security reasons):

URL:
https://api.XXX.com/product/getStocks?access_token=XXX&product_id=XXX&lang=en

RESPONSE WHEN I VISIT THE URL:
{"code":0,"stocks":[{"warehouse":"XXX","stock_list":[{"poa_id":"","poa":"","stock":39,"stock_msg":"In stock, usually dispatched in 1 business day"}]}],"lang":"en"}

I would like to display the "stock" and "stock_msg" results on my website based on product_id input.

Answer (score 0):

Using liquid is almost certainly going to be your best bet, but product stock is tied to **variants** rather than **products.** This is some code to show variant quantities:

```
<div class="variant-inventory">
  {% if product.variants.first.inventory_management == "shopify" %}
     {% if product.variants.first.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
        We currently have {{product.variants.first.inventory_quantity }} in stock.
     {% else %}
         The product is out of stock
     {% endif %}
  {% else %}
    There are {{product.variants.first.inventory_quantity}} in stock.
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

It's probably not possible to get the product quantities through basic REST API Calls, as I believe those are private quantities that require Authentication. See here: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/inventory